# Appengine - Upload to Google Spreadsheet datastore values

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, bigtable, google-sheets

I´d like to know how to upload to a Google Spreadsheet, values stored in the database of my application.

**Objective:**
Connecting to Google Spreadsheet and automatically fill in a chart in the admin area with values that were passed by the upload.

I've been giving a look in the docs and it seems to me that I have to use Bulk Loader.
Is this the only way? If yes how to configure the Handler if I have a spreadsheet as a link to [link text](https://spreadsheets1.google.com/ccc?key=twMTYv_Cxfp7XLhw50NW8og#gid=0)

Someone could make a script to access the Google Spreadsheet and pass the values of a Model?

**Model:**

```
class User (db.Model):
    photo= db.BlobProperty()
    name = db.StringProperty (required = True)
    surname = db.StringProperty (required = True)
    adress = db.PostalAddressProperty (required = True)
    phone = db.PhoneNumberProperty (required = True)
```

Comment: SO works best when you have tried something yourself. If you want others to write your code, then you should pay them.

Answer (score 3):

The Bulk Loader has nothing to do with interacting with a Google Docs Spreadsheet. It is used for adding records to your application's datastore.

To manipulate a Google Spreadsheet, you'll need to use the [Google Spreadsheet API](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/overview/), which you could easily find on your own using Google.

No one here is going to write this code for you. This is not a free code-writing service. If you write some code that doesn't work and need some help figuring out why, edit your question and include the code along with a thorough description of what isn't working and why if you have any idea.

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look first at the Google Spreadsheet API. I misread the information on the Bulk Uploader.